# How do I make id from one table be the same on another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a relation between two ids. Let's say one is 'id' (on table first) other is 'the_id' (on table second).

So this is what I wrote, but obviously this only selects. What do I do or write in phpMyAdmin to make the relation?

```
SELECT 
f.id, s.the_id 
FROM first AS f 
LEFT JOIN second
AS s ON f.id= s.the_id
```

Comment: The LEFT JOIN already did the relation. What aches you?

Comment: I'm not thinking straight. Yes thank you.

Comment: *what do i do or write in phpmyadmin to make the relation?* The data relation is set by FOREIGN KEY creation.